# Converting JSON to an object based off of another property

Tags: c#, json.net

I am writing some models and assigning them `JsonProperty` attributes so I can parse them using `Newtonsoft.Json`. My problem is that my Laravel backend is returning a polymorphic relationship so it means that my property can be of a dynamic type.

Owned by a user:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "owner_id": 1,
    "owner_type": "App\\Models\\User",
    "created_at": "2019-04-21 08:57:53",
    "updated_at": "2019-04-21 08:57:53",
    "owner": {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "testuser",
        "email": "test123@mail.com",
        "email_verified_at": null,
        "created_at": "2019-04-20 10:23:50",
        "updated_at": "2019-04-20 10:23:50"
    }
}
```

Owned by a group:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "owner_id": 1,
    "owner_type": "App\\Models\\Group",
    "created_at": "2019-04-21 08:57:53",
    "updated_at": "2019-04-21 08:57:53",
    "owner": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Administration",
        "created_at": "2019-04-01 00:00:00",
        "updated_at": "2019-04-01 00:00:00",
        "color": {
            "id": 52,
            "hex": "#426D42",
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to map the `owner` to the appropriate model class in my C# project. The main model is `Vehicle`:

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace OmegaAPI.Models
{
    public class Vehicle
    {
        [JsonProperty("owner_type")]
        private string OwnerType { get; set; }


        [JsonProperty("owner")]
        public object Owner { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And for example I have the `User` and `Group` model classes that can be owners of the `Vehicle`. How do I convert `owner` to the appropriate model class using the `OwnerType` property?

Comment: You can use `enum` for `OwnerType` and then in `switch` statement you can use appropriate model in each `case`.

Comment: Is `owner`s object properties changed with respect to `OwnerType` or they are fixed for each `OwnerType` ?

Comment: `Owner`'s properties are changed since it needs to be cast to a different model in regards to the `OwnerType` @er-sho

Comment: So what about my first comment. Does it helpful to you?

Comment: @er-sho Can you provide code example? I am not sure if I understand it correctly

Comment: Yes sure but could you please add one more json example with different `OwnerType` so it  can be helpful to me?

Comment: @er-sho I have updated the question

Comment: I added my answer below try it and let me know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** You need to create one enum that contains all possible members that are value with `owner_type` in json

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public enum EnumOwnerType
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "App\\Models\\User")]
    User,
    [EnumMember(Value = "App\\Models\\Group")]
    Group
}
```

You need to add reference to your project for assembly `System.Runtime.Serialization` and in your program you have to import some namespaces like

- `using System.Runtime.Serialization;` for [EnumMemberAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.enummemberattribute?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8).
- `using Newtonsoft.Json;`
- `using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;` for [StringEnumConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_StringEnumConverter.htm).
- `using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;` for [JObject](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm).

**2)** Modify your `Vehicle` class like below

```
public class Vehicle
{
    [JsonProperty("owner_type")]
    public EnumOwnerType OwnerType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("owner")]
    public JObject Owner { get; set; }
}
```

In above class the property

- `OwnerType` is of type `EnumOwnerType`.
- `Owner` is of type `JObject`.

**3)** This is your sample model for `User`

```
class User
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string  username { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string email_verified_at { get; set; }
    public DateTime? created_at { get; set; }
    public DateTime? updated_at { get; set; }
}
```

And this is for `Group`

```
class Group
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public DateTime? created_at { get; set; }
    public DateTime? updated_at { get; set; }
    public _Color color { get; set; }
}

class _Color
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string hex { get; set; }
    public DateTime? created_at { get; set; }
    public DateTime? updated_at { get; set; }
}
```

**Usage:** Deserialization Code

```
string json = "Your json here";

Vehicle vehicle = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Vehicle>(json);

switch (vehicle.OwnerType)
{
    case EnumOwnerType.User:
        User user = vehicle.Owner.ToObject<User>();
        break;

    case EnumOwnerType.Group:
        Group group = vehicle.Owner.ToObject<Group>();
        break;
}
```

In above `switch` block, the cases automatically executed with respect to `OwnerType` enum and `Owner` is a `JObject` will type cast your `owner` json object to appropriate model either `User` or `Group`.

**Output:** (From Debugger)

1) For your first json with `"owner_type": "App\\Models\\User"`.

[image]

2) For your second json with `"owner_type": "App\\Models\\Group"`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

just deserialize to dynamic. You can get what you want by using an ExpandoObject.

```
var converter = new ExpandoObjectConverter();    
dynamic customer1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(jsonString, converter);
Console.WriteLine(customer1.owner.username);
```